# algolia magento module ordered_qty as ranking attribute blocking cron executions

Tags: magento, search, algolia

We moved Algolia search from our local development environment to our staging environment.  On staging we have 144,000 sample orders and 100,000 products.  Both of these numbers are smaller than our production environment.

We inserted our app id and other credentials and saved.  We're using AOE scheduler to execute our crons.  algoliasearch_run_queue has been running for 5 hours now and it seems to be making the same queries:

SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `o....

I believe this is related to ranking = ordered_qty.  This cron is holding up all processing of subsequent crons, meaning other magento task, (order emails, indexing, etc) will not take place during the time this one is running.

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

An improvement has been done in 1.4.3 but will probably not resolve the issue for such big store. Computing ordered_qty can indeed be long but it's used to have a good relevance.